# This code is working in a DB, but while i am trying compile it in another DB. it is throwing error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
create or replace procedure rebuild_indexes(
    p_table_name in varchar2 := 'SYSTEM'
) as
SQL_STR VARCHAR2(1000);
USERNAME VARCHAR2(50);
begin

    Select USER into USERNAME from dual;

    for indexes_to_rebuild in
    (
        select index_name
        from dba_indexes
        where owner =  USERNAME
           -- and table_name = p_table_name
    ) loop
        SQL_STR := 'alter index '||USERNAME||'.'||indexes_to_rebuild.index_Name|| ' rebuild';
        execute immediate SQL_STR;
    end loop;
end;
```

**EDIT:**
The Error i get:

> 1- Error(16,51): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'INDEXES_TO_REBUILD'
>   use is invalid 2- Error(11,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 3-
>   Error(12,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 4-
>   Error(16,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: 1- Error(16,51): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'INDEXES_TO_REBUILD' use is invalid
2- Error(11,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3- Error(12,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
4- Error(16,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

It seems the user lacks a select right on dba_indexes. Have a DBA grant the user the right:

```
grant select on dba_indexes to thatusername;
```

Or better, as your are only interested in the user's indexes anyway, don't read `dba_indexes` at all, but `user_indexes` instead. Change

```
select index_name
from dby_indexes
where owner =  USERNAME
```

to

```
select index_name
from user_indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The user which you have logged in does not have privileges to view `DATA DICTIONARY` objects.

So, Login first from a `SYSDBA` user and execute

```
GRANT SELECT on DBA_INDEXES to youruser;
```

Or, If you need the user to have privileges to view all the data dictionary ( `all_objects` etc.. )

```
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO youruser;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `Select USER into USERNAME from dual;` just use `USER` directly. Try this one:

```
for indexes_to_rebuild in
(
    SELECT INDEX_NAME
    FROM USER_INDEXES
    WHERE INDEX_TYPE IN ('NORMAL', 'BITMAP', 'FUNCTION-BASED BITMAP', 'FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL')
        AND PARTITIONED = 'NO'
        AND TEMPORARY = 'N'
        -- and table_name = p_table_name
) loop
    SQL_STR := 'alter index '||USER||'.'||indexes_to_rebuild.index_Name|| ' rebuild';
    execute immediate SQL_STR;
end loop;
```

For partitioned indexes you have to execute `REBUILD` separately for each (sub-)partition.